# PHP OOP connection to MYSQL (constructor vs. passing instance) efficiency

Tags: php, mysql, performance, oop, constructor

I've been wondering about the effiency of OOP connections. The example structure is shown below. Each class seperated by folder and class name. For example:

```
/mysql/mysql.class.php //holds general connect and disconnect functions
/mysql/query.class.php //holds all the queries made to the db (uses basic mysql ^ )
/library/application.class.php //holds all the algorithms (uses queries to db ^ )
```

When it comes to executing an algorithm, the `application.class.php` calls upon `query.class.php` (when it needs to query) which calls `mysql.class.php` for a connection.

Which one of these two ways is correct (if any or both)? Is there a simpler and more efficient way of doing this?

Here is the same way of doing two things **(Which is more efficient??)** :

```
require_once('/mysql/mysql.class.php ');
require_once('/mysql/query.class.php ');

$mysqlClass = new MYSQL();
$queryClass = new Query();

class Application {                
  public function getVar() {         
    $param = foo;         
    $db = $mysqlClass->connect(); //connection to mysql
    $queryClass->callsomequerymethod($db, $param); //pass the db connection to function
  } 
}
```

**VS**

```
class Application {     
  private $db;      
  public function __construct(DatabaseConnection $db, QueryClass $queryclass){
    $this->db = $db;     
  }           
  public function getVar() {         
    $param = foo;         
    $db = $this->db;
    $queryclass->callsomequerymethod($db, $param);
  } 
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can't comment on efficiency, but the second method would be better since the variables are neatly scoped within the class that uses them, as opposed to lying in the global namespace.

A further modification I would make is move the `require` statements within the constructor so that those files are included only when the class that uses them (in your case `Application`) is instantiated.

Comment: In the second method, is it alright to pass the database connection instance to the `QueryClass`? Or should the database instance be created in constructor of the `QueryClass` as well? I'm trying to figure out if passing instances of classes (specifically MYSQL database connections) would be considered a *best practice* or if it violates *good programming style* ?

Comment: It is a good idea to allow passing the connection object, but I would personally give it a default value of NULL which creates a default connection. This way, if you always connect to a standard DB, you don't need to worry about it, yet at the same time it gives you the flexibility to create connections to other DBs as well.

Comment: thats the way I currently have it implemented. I'm just trying to figure out if there a way to limit the number of require statements and class instances. (I have way too many on some pages :x ) The require statements become a huge load (which is why I try to pass object instances into classes), but I dont know if its good practice

Comment: You should create a loader class that is responsible for requiring PHP files. Even better, if you're using PHP 5, use `spl_autoload_register` to automatically load in classes as and when required. [http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.spl-autoload-register.php]